# What is a shortcut key to create Command or Routed Event?

Tags: wpf, command, shortcut, routed-events

For example, the shortcut key to create Dependency Property or Attached Property is <kbd>Ctrl + K + X</kbd>.

If then, What is the shortcut key to create Command or Routed Event?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This topic is not related to my code.
I want to know the shortcut key of the Visual Studio to generate Command or Routed Event.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski its a tool question, not a code question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of all code snippets in VS 2019:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/ide/visual-csharp-code-snippets?view=vs-2019

As you can see, there are none of the snippets available specifically for your purpose. However, you can write quickly your own, like this guy: http://interactiveasp.net/blogs/natesstuff/archive/2008/10/15/routed-event-code-snippet.aspx did.

Or, if you using the Prism framework, you can download the template pack (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BrianLagunas.PrismTemplatePack) that contain some snippets for e.g. a DelegateCommand.